# Not finding the next correct date(s)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Can anyone please explain why this is happening when i run this code? I just want to dates to follow each other.

```
        let d = new Date(),
        day = d.getDay(),
        date = d.getDate();

    let diff = day - 1;
    let start = date - diff;

    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 1)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 2)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 3)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 4)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 5)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 6)))
    console.log(new Date(d.setDate(start + 7)))
```

[image: output console.logs from above]

**UPDATE:**

Liam's comments worked perfectly, but I need it to start from the first weekday (monday) and get it to the last weekday (sunday), right now it starts from this day

Comment: You only have to add one day after the first set `console.log(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)))` since `setDate()` changes the initial object.

Comment: Makes so much sense thanks!!, Do you have any idea to find the first weekday aswell, I have a openinhours table that always starts with monday, so with your code, it starts from this day

Comment: Yes, you can reduce the current weekday `d.getDay()`. For example `new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 1))`. You will find many examples about this on stack.

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved so much time for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add one day after the first set `console.log(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)))` since `setDate()` changes the initial object.

```js
//REM: Now
var tMonday = new Date();

//REM: Take off the current weekday to get sunday
//REM: Be aware of how to handle sundays here, since those are zero
tMonday.setDate(tMonday.getDate() - tMonday.getDay());

//REM: Add a day to get monday
tMonday.setDate(tMonday.getDate() + 1);

//REM: Now we can create a loop of six until sunday
for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
  console.log(
    new Date(tMonday.setDate(tMonday.getDate() + 1))
  )
};
```

*Be aware how you want to handle sunday on this logic. If it counts to the current week or next.*